# R : Odd Behavior with Width On Layout

Tags: r, layout, plot

I'm trying to have my bottom graphs have widths proportional to the length of the month.

However, I end up with

[image]

I have 2 levels of graphs, 1 with a larger plot that takes an entire row and another with 12 plots that take up the entire 2nd row.

For the 2nd row plots, I wish to have their widths proportional to the length of the month so I do

```
layout(matrix(c(rep(1,12),2:13),nrow=2,byrow=T),widths=c(1,months))

months 
[1] 31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31
```

The odd thing is when I manually adjust the numbers in the widths array ( using 1s and 2s). The sizes do fluctuate accordingly. However, in this case. This appears to not be the case.

January is much too short. Am I missing something in my logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have only 12 plots on the bottom line but you provided 13 values for the `widths=` argument (number `1` plus all `months` values). Just use `widths=months` to get the result you need. Number of values you provided with the widths= argument should be equal to the number of plots in one longest row but not to the number of all plots.

```
months<-c( 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31)    
layout(matrix(c(rep(1,12),2:13),nrow=2,byrow=T),widths=months)
layout.show(n = 13)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Unfortunately, I did run into the same issue with [1] 31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31. So I'm confused as to how to approach this.

Comment: @Django Then you have to provide additional information in your question (sample data). As you can see from plot in answer - space for the 3. plot (2. plot in 2. row) is smaller (February) than for other plots.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help so far. I noticed that my layout.show(n=13) displays the exact same thing. I'm taking in a a vector for each plot called days [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
[22] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31  and im feeding that into plot(days,y_vals,type="l",xaxt="n",ann=FALSE) for each of the bottom plots.

Comment: Another odd fact, when I remove widths from layout entirely nothing changes. If I add labels to January, I can see that it still iterates from 1 to 31.

Comment: @Django widths= argument doesn't limit data you plot, it just sets the space for the plot.

Comment: Wouldn't it imply that the widths argument was having no effect if it remained the same before and after I specified the # of days in the month?

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Didzis Elferts is a good answer. Mine juste to note that when you deal with time series you can use `xts` package. Specially that plot are done in the base graphics .
here an example:

- I use `monthly.apply` to split my object.
- I use plot.xts to plts my time series.

First , I generate some random data

```
library(xts)
days <- seq.Date( as.Date("2011-01-01"), as.Date("2011-12-31") ,1)
dat <- xts(rnorm(365),days)

## I use monthly apply to compute months widths.
## no need to give them by hand.
widths <-  coredata(apply.monthly(dat,length))
par(bg="lightyellow", mar=c(2,2,2,0))
layout(matrix(c(rep(1,12),2:13),nrow=2,byrow=T),widths=widths*2)

mon <- months(days,abbreviate=T)
plot(dat,main = 'my year time series')

apply.monthly(dat,function(x) {
  if(unique(format((index(x)),'%m')) =='01') {#JAN
    par(mar=c(2,2,2,0))   ## special case of JAN because it contians y axis 
    plot(x,main='')
  }
  else{
    par( mar=c(2,0,2,0))
    plot(x,main='',ylab='')
  }
})
```

[image]

Note that : JAN panel is not smaller than Feb one. It contains the y axis.